# C++ streamsize prec = cout.precision(3) - How does it work?

Tags: c++, copy, precision, cout, assign

I am kind of newbie in using c++. I have a quick question, probably a dumb question.

```
streamsize prec = cout.precision(3);
```

As I understand correctly this declaration works like that: set the `cout` precision to 3, but assign the previous precision value to `prec`.

Also, simply, we can assign a function result (say a math addition function) to a variable:

```
int z = addition(3,4);
```

In the second one, it does the calculation and assigns the results to the variable `z`, not the previous value or a default value. Is my understanding correct? What is the difference between them?

Comment: Not a dumb question, don't be so shy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What value a function returns depends entirely on that particular function. Most functions simply return a result of their operation.

The state-setting functions in standard library streams (such as `precision`) are a bit unusual in their interface of "I set a new value and return the old one," but it's still perfectly valid, as long as the function's behaviour is documented (which it is in their case).

Comment: So, it depends on the function, and its particular behavior in returning a value. cout.precision just returns the previous value. then to change the precision and assign it to prec I should do the following. std::cout.precision(3); streamsize prec = cout.precision(); Thanks a lot.